# Changing column order of multiple dataframes by iterating via a for-loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to change the column order of multiple dataframes containing the same column names. To do this I am trying a for loop, but the column order does not change for any of the data frames.

There are four columns in the following order col_4,col_3,col_2,col_1 and I want them in the following order col_1, col_2, col_4, col_3

The code I have tried is as follows. I am relatively new to python, so apologies if I am making some rookie mistake

```
for df in df_1,df_2,df_3:
    df=df.reindex([col_1, col_2, col_4, col_3],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can symply use the `dataframe["col_name_1", "col_name_2", "col_name_3"]`.

Here an example :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 3)),
                     columns=["A", "C", "B"])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 3)),
                     columns=["C", "B", "A"])
data3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 3)),
                     columns=["B", "C", "A"])

print(data1)
#    A  C  B
# 0  5  1  3
# 1  8  8  9
print(data2)
#    C  B  A
# 0  3  2  0
# 1  5  4  2
print(data3)
#    B  C  A
# 0  4  6  7
# 1  4  8  4

new_columns_order = ["A", "B", "C"]

# Reorder data2 et data3 columns according to the data1 columns
list_dataframe = [data1, data2, data3]
for i, df in enumerate(list_dataframe):
    list_dataframe[i] = df[new_columns_order]

print("Data1:\n", list_dataframe[0])
#    A  B  C
# 0  7  6  8
# 1  3  0  7
print("Data2:\n", list_dataframe[1])
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  8  9
# 1  8  9  7
print("Data3:\n", list_dataframe[2])
#    A  B  C
# 0  8  9  4
# 1  3  4  9
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried executing the code, but column order for data2 and data3 does not change.

Comment: Tried with this as well but the problem persists. When I reorder the column without the for loop it works fine, but the change doesn't get saved when in for loop

Comment: It's right. In the loop, if you just modify the current dataframe, you're doing the modification but the object isn't save. You need to save the new dataframe. One way to do is to save all the dataframes in a list (as I have done is the edited answer) and rewrite the list in the loop. Otherwise, you lose your modifications.